# Oracle Apex: Multiple fields with each submit button issue

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using older version of Apex 5.0.3 and new to Apex.

I have six text fields in one page with six submit buttons each. Buttons are mapped as follows

- Button Name: "Save and complete Later" Advanced - Request Source: "SAVE"
- Button Name: "Submit For Approval" Advanced - Request Source: "APPLY_CHANGES"
- Button Name: "Submit for Quality Review" Advanced - Request Source: "UPDATE"
- Button Name: "Submit for Pilot" Advanced - Request Source: "UPDATE ROW"
- Button Name: "Approve Task" Advanced - Request Source: "CHANGE"
- Button Name: "Retired" Advanced - Request Source: "APPLY"

Now, I got a requirement to add three other fields. I am wondering, Request sources such as UPDATE, APPLY, APPLY_CHANGES are predefined data or how do I add new request sources?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXgUo.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yezq.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the screen shots. My issue is linking between the text field and the button. How do I get the data from the text field when button is clicked? sorry for many questions.

Answer (score 3):

By default, request name is equal to button name, but you can change it to anything you want. Therefore, go for it - create new 3 buttons, name them as you wish (e.g. `P1_BTN_NEW_BUTTON_1`) and (optionally) name the request.

However, what you *might* need to do is this: usually, buttons submit the page. Additionally, there's a **process** that runs when certain button is pressed. For example, you might be calling a stored procedure which does *something* and returns the message (whether it succeeded or not) via its `OUT` parameter into a (hidden) Apex item (e.g. `P1_MESSAGE_BTN_1`) which can then be used in success message as `&P1_MESSAGE_BTN_1.` (note leading ampersand `&` and trailing dot `.`).

Furthermore, you should specify **condition** which has to be satisfied in order for the process to run. How? By setting the "When button pressed" property, so that process fires only when that particular button is pressed (not *any* button).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am wondering, how the Request name is linked to an action in the button? I have created the process by setting "When button pressed" but if I add any other Request source apart from I mentioned such as APPLY, UPDATE etc, the request is not submitted and value is not stored to database. Please help on how to link the button action to a new Request Source?

Comment: What Littlefoot said is exactly right. Your new buttons should have a Behavior Action of "Submit Page". And the new processes you create for them should use the Server-Side Condition "When Button Pressed", where you choose the button name you created above. Unless multiple processes are run from the same button, you shouldn't ALSO have to set Type/Value.

Comment: I have added screen shots of the text fields and buttons. My issue is linking between the text field and the button. How do I get the data from the text field when button is clicked? sorry for many questions.

Comment: Get *where*? Once (submit) button is pressed, item's name is stored into session state and you can use its value simply by referencing the item as (for example) `:P1_DATE`. If it (the process which runs once button is pressed) calls a stored procedure which accepts date as a parameter, you'd `p_my_procedure(:P1_DATE);`

Comment: Thank you for more detailed update. But it seems my current application is not using any procedure. It is using "Request Source Type [Deprecated]" = "Static value  [Deprecated]" and "Request Source  = "SAVE" as in the screen shot to trigger validation and database update. If I remove "Request Source" value, validation and update doesn't work. I am stuck on how "Request Source" value is created and link to the process? Please help.